# Enable kiosk mode programmatically for windows store apps

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, kiosk-mode

We are developing a Windows Store app for a client. The app is designed to run in kiosk mode.

Is there a way to make it easy for the user to enable kiosk mode (Assigned Access) for the app?

Ideally I would like to pop a dialog with an "Accept" button which handles all the necessary configurations.

Comment: If you find the answer below sufficient can you please accept? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this programmatically that I know of. However, you can write a Powershell script that will do what you are asking. This Powershell script could then be ran by your client or as part of the initial installation of the app.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449310%28v=winembedded.82%29.aspx